# Using <script> tag within editable email notification dialog in Jenkins

Tags: javascript, html, jenkins

I am writing this simple html in the editable email notification dialog box:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"> </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "this is from JS";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

However I am unable to see the string " this is from JS" in the generated email. Not sure what am I doing wrong ? Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your JS, but it seems that you never call it.
Try running in a load or ready function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "this is from JS";
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "this is from JS";
});

</script>
```

I think this is what you are trying to do.

UPDATE:

Alright, I found another function that will work for you. here is the the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ngdj9s8b/2/).

```
<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "this is from JS";
    });
  </script>
</body>
```